# Unresolved name `Binary` when using the ftp crate

Tags: ftp, rust, rust-crates

I am downloading a file from a FTP server using 
[the ftp crate](https://crates.io/crates/ftp):

```
extern crate ftp;
extern crate chrono;

use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::str;
use std::io::{Result, Write};
use ftp::FtpStream;
use chrono::*;


fn main() {

    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    ftpgp(&args[1], &args[2], &args[3], &args[4]).unwrap_or_else(|err|
        panic!("{}", err)
    );

}

fn ftpgp(addr: &str, user: &str, pass: &str, remote_path: &str,) -> Result<()> {
    let dt = Local::now();
    let now = dt.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").to_string();

    let mut ftp_stream = try!(FtpStream::connect((addr, 21)));
    try!(ftp_stream.login(user, pass));

    ftp_stream.cwd(remote_path).unwrap();
    let file_list = try!(ftp_stream.nlst(None));

    let files: Vec<String> = file_list.into_iter()
        .filter(|name| name.ends_with(".zip"))
        .collect();

    for file in files {
        try!(ftp_stream.retr(file.as_str(), |stream| {
            let mut file = File::create(file.clone()).unwrap();
            let mut buf = [0; 2048];

            loop {
              match stream.read(&mut buf) {
                Ok(0) => break,
                Ok(n) => file.write_all(&buf[0..n]).unwrap(),
                Err(err) => return Err(err)
              };
            }

            Ok(())
        }));
        println!("{} Saving: {}", now, file);

        ftp_stream.rm(file.as_str()).unwrap();
        println!("{} Delete from ftp: {}", now, file);
    }

    ftp_stream.quit()
}
```

But zip files are corrupt after downloading:

```
   unzip -t sample.zip 
   Archive:  sample.zip
   warning [sample.zip]:  252314 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
      (attempting to process anyway)
   file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  252314
      (attempting to re-compensate)
   testing: sample.pdf  
      error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
   file #2:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  67841095
      (attempting to re-compensate)
   file #2:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  67841095
   file #3:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  68093906
```

I have [set the type of file to be transferred](http://mattnenterprise.github.io/rust-ftp/ftp/types/enum.FormatControl.html), but I don't know how.

Like this:

```
ftp_stream.transfer_type(Binary);
```

is not working.

```
error: unresolved name `Binary`
```

Comment: Try `ftp_stream.transfer_type(::ftp::types::FileType::Binary)`.

Comment: It's works! Thank you very much.
Can you add this info to the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a name resolution issue.

You have declared a dependency on an external crate:

```
extern crate ftp;
```

And then imported *one* symbol from this crate:

```
use ftp::FtpStream;
```

Therefore, the symbol `::ftp::types::FileType::Binary` is not in scope.

You can either use the full name, or modify your import:

- `use ftp::{FtpStream, types}` means you can write `types::FileType::Binary`
- `use ftp::types::FileType` means you can write `FileType::Binary`
- `use ftp::types::FileType::Binary` means you can write `Binary`

It's really a matter of taste.

Also note that if you wish you can put the `use` statement in the only function using `Binary` to tighten the scope of the import; it's something I like to make it clearer where the imports are used (and where they are not).